# Window 8 app to send email in c# code

Tags: windows-phone-8

I create a new window phone app to sending email to any user.I am already search on google but dn't get any result.basically this app is like a contact us page.

Suggest me best book for learning window phone app

Comment: The problem is that StackOverflow is not a book recommendation service. We're also not about finding a library that does X, or telling you what the best approach is out of A, B, and C. We're about solving programming problems, dabbling in algorithms, mostly. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we use `EmailComposeTask` to send emails from Windows Phone. Details of `EmailComposeTask` is in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

If you do not want to use `EmailComposeTask`, then you can review this article: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/send-email-with-attachments-without-using-emailcomposetask-with-mailmessage

And for your other question regarding learning Windows Phone development, start with these video tutorials.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-01a-Introducing-Windows-Phone-8-Development-Part-1